# Select data of a single column of all records using linq command

Tags: linq

I want to select data of a particular column of all records using Linq command.Here is my code

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult DeleteRole(RoleManager model)
    {

      string [] getRole = (from r in Session.Query<RoleManager>()
                            select r.roleName).ToArray();

      foreach( var myrole in getRole)
        {
            model.roleName = myrole.roleName;
        }

        return View(model);
    }
```

but it is not working.Can you please guide me.

Comment: What is `RoleManager` in this case? And why is your `DeleteRole` method not actually deleting anything?

Comment: In future, please give more details than "it is not working" which is like going to the doctor and saying "I'm not well" and expecting a diagnosis with no more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to select `roleName` twice - you've already done the right thing by selecting it  the first time. You're also overwriting the `roleName` field/property in the model multiple times, whereas presumably you want to retain *all* the values. It's not clear what `model` is meant to be doing at all, to be honest - but you should be able to create a view of just the roles:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult DeleteRole(RoleManager model)
{
    string[] roles = (from r in Session.Query<RoleManager>()
                      select r.roleName).ToArray();
    return View(roles);
}
```

Or using the `Select` extension method directly, which is simpler in this case IMO:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult DeleteRole(RoleManager model)
{
    string[] roles = Session.Query<RoleManager>()
                            .Select(r => r.roleName)
                            .ToArray();
    return View(roles);
}
```

... or if you *do* need to modify the model, you'll need the model itself to support multiple roles.

Note that this isn't actually doing any deleting, which makes it a fairly odd action name in my opinion...

Comment: I am just geeting values of roles in HttpGet method,i am deleting it in HttpPost method.I tried your answer 2 but it is giving error The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.String[]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'MvcMembership.Models.RoleManager'

Comment: @Wasfa: Well yes, you'd need to change the view as well - but fundamentally you need to work out what you're trying to do. If this isn't deleting a role, you shouldn't call it `DeleteRole` IMO. If you want a single model, that model needs to contain everything you need in the view - which may mean it has a *collection* of role names within it.

Comment: @JonSkeet if the path ..../deleterole displays roles to be potentially deleted on the subsequent POST what is wrong with that? Seems logical to me.

Comment: @happygilmore: It's not deleting roles - it's displaying them. I'd use a URL which only displayed them, and then use a deleterole URL for the actual deletion. Anyway, that's clearly not the problem - just a side note really.